# segmented control in iPhone application

Tags: iphone

I've put UIsegment Control in my IPhone application.To load the pages I've this function
- (void) segmentSelected:(id)segmentedCntl{
    NSLog(@"Selected Segment Index = %d", [segmentedCntl selectedSegmentIndex]);
    int index = [segmentedCntl selectedSegmentIndex];

```
ViewController *viewController = (ViewController *) controller;
NSString *xPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"item[%d]/a", (index + 1)];
NSArray *items = [element nodesForXPath:xPath error:nil];
if([items count] > 0){
    CXMLElement *itemElement = (CXMLElement *) [items objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *url = [[itemElement attributeForName:@"href"] stringValue];
    NSLog(@"url is &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&& %@", url);
    if([url startsWith:@"#"]){
    }else{
        NSString *fullURL = [URLLoader getURL:url];
        if(fullURL != nil){
            if([fullURL contains:@"?"]){
                fullURL = [fullURL stringByAppendingString:@"&iPhoneMode=app"];
            }else{
                fullURL = [fullURL stringByAppendingString:@"?iPhoneMode=app"];
            }
            [viewController showURL:fullURL cacheDuration:kPageCacheDuartion];               
        }
    }
}
```

}

But the segmentControl is not clickable.Please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Namastey saikamesh

Please check proper u'r UISegmentControl property setting it will be working.